# Can't delete post if it has a rating?

Tags: python

I'm having some problem with python. I have created a baking blog where you can rate the recipes. If a recipe doesn't have a rating, you can delete it. However, if a recipe has one or multiple ratings, you can't delete it. I don't quite know what is wrong. I get an error message that says
[SQL: UPDATE rating SET recipe_id=? WHERE rating.id = ?]
[parameters: (None, 25)]. So I think that it's something wrong when I ad a rating? That it doesn't connect to the post?

```
@app.route("/recipes/<int:recipe_id>")
def recipe(recipe_id):
    recipe = Recipe.query.get_or_404(recipe_id)
    form = RatingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.picture.data:
            picture_file = save_picture(form.picture.data)
            recipe.image_file = picture_file
    avg_rating = db.session.query(func.avg(Rating.rating).label('average')).filter(Rating.recipe_id == recipe_id).first()[0]
    image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + recipe.image_file)
    return render_template('recipe_page.html', title=recipe.title, post=recipe, form=form, avg_rating=avg_rating, image_file=image_file)
```

```
@app.route("/recipes/<int:recipe_id>/delete", methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def delete_recipe(recipe_id):
    recipe = Recipe.query.get_or_404(recipe_id)
    if recipe.user != current_user:
        abort(403)
    db.session.delete(recipe)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your recipe has been deleted', 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

```
@app.route("/recipes/<int:recipe_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def rating(recipe_id):
    current_recipe = Recipe.query.get_or_404(recipe_id)
    form = RatingForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            new_rating = Rating(rating=form.rating.data,
                                user=current_user,
                                recipe=current_recipe)
            db.session.add(new_rating)
            try:
                db.session.commit()
                form.rating.data = ""
                flash('You have voted!', 'success')
            except Exception as e:
                db.session.rollback()
                app.logger.critical(f'Error while voting: {new_rating}')
                app.logger.exception(e)
                flash('There was an error when voting. Try again later.', 'danger')
        else:
            flash('You are not logged in. You need to be logged in to be able to rate a recipe!', 'danger')
    avg_rating = db.session.query(func.avg(Rating.rating).label('average')).filter(Rating.recipe_id == recipe_id).first()[0]
    return render_template('recipe_page.html',
                           title=current_recipe.title,
                           avg_rating=avg_rating,
                           post=current_recipe,
                           form=form
                           )
```

```
class Recipe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='baking.png')
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship(User, backref=db.backref('recipes', lazy=True))
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=False)
    category = db.relationship(Category, backref=db.backref('recipes', lazy=True))
    number_of_ingredients = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Recipe (id='{self.id}', title='{self.title}', date_posted='{self.date_posted}', content='{self.content}', image_file='{self.image_file}', category='{self.category}', number_of_ingredients='{self.number_of_ingredients}')>"
```

```
class Rating(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship(User, backref=db.backref('ratings', lazy=True))
    recipe_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipe.id'), nullable=False)
    recipe = db.relationship(Recipe, backref=db.backref('ratings', lazy=True))
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Rating (id='{self.id}', rating='{self.rating}', user_id='{self.user_id}', recipe_id='{self.recipe_id}')>"
```

The error message I get is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: rating.recipe_id
[SQL: UPDATE rating SET recipe_id=? WHERE rating.id = ?]
[parameters: (None, 25)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/gkpj)
[2021-08-23 11:43:38,200] [INFO] [werkzeug] [_internal:113] - 127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2021 11:43:38] "POST /recipes/13/delete HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. Also, search for the error you got, just in order to understand what it means and what causes it. BTW: I think your problem is with SQL, not Python!

Comment: When you delete a recipe, what do you want to happen to the corresponding ratings?

Comment: Hi! If i delete a recipe I would like for it all to disappear, both the post and the rating. Maybe that's my problem?

Comment: Hi again! An idea I have is to add the ratings to the delete route somehow. Does that sound correct?